# Problem with a really simple program in java IF statement condition is being ignored

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a program and my if statement doesn't give the expected output.
 I searched and found a tutorial on java if statements and copied the code
on the tutorial into eclipse.

```
    int value = 1
    if (value == 3); {
    System.out.println("hello world")
    }
```

The problem is whatever I change the value to, the system still outputs "hello world".
It doesn't make much sense to me I've done much more complicated programs in the past.
Is there something stupid that I'm missing?
Thanks Brad.
,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon in line 2 terminates the if and it should be removed

```
int value = 1;
if (value == 3) {
    System.out.println("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bala R I've been struggling with this for a while now.  Works perfectly.  Do you guys mark threads "solved" on this forum and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your formatting.

```
int value = 1;
if (value == 3); // extra ;
// totally unrelated block of code.
{
   System.out.println("hello world")
}
```

Which is why I use me IDE to do my formatting.

Comment: Missing semi after int value = 1

Comment: Cheers, took that from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, this code will *not* compile because you're missing a semicolon when doing variable assignment:

```
int value = 1;
```